# CSS - How to make search box full height inside menu bar?

Tags: html, css, menu, height, searchbar

I was trying to make this category search box to fill the heigh of of the menu bar, but I was not able to make it work and be the same height.

How can I achieve this? What I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```css
.fa {
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
/*hack stack-overflow*/

ul::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li.left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
li.right {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
li span:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
li#login {
  position: relative;
}
li#login form {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
li#login:hover form {
  display: block;
}
input.login_field {
  margin: 10px;
}
#submit-div {
  text-align: center;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.nav-list {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
#dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
#dropdown:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.current-selection {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.in-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
#search-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
#search-box:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.go-button {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.go-button:hover {
  background-color: #ff7300;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="left"><a class="fa fa-home" href="index.jsp">&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="left"><a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="#home">&nbsp;Carrello</a>
    </li>

    <li class="left"><span id="totale" class="fa fa-money">&nbsp;&euro;0</span>
    </li>


    <li id="search" class="left">
      <div id="form-wrapper">
        <button class="go-button fa fa-search"></button>
        <span class="nav-list">
  <span class="current-selection">
  </span>
        <select id="dropdown">
          <option value="books-and-ebooks">Books & eBooks</option>
          <option value="audiobooks">Audiobooks</option>
          <option value="dvds">DVDs</option>
          <option value="other-resources">Other Resources</option>
          <option value="random">Random</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <div class="in-wrap">
          <input type="text" name="query" id="search-box">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="right"><a class="fa fa-user-plus" href="">&nbsp;Signup</a>
    </li>
    <li id="login" class="right">
      <a class="fa fa-sign-in" href="">&nbsp;Login</a>
      <form id="login_form" action="login" method="post">
        <input id="login_username" class="login_field" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <br />
        <input id="login_password" class="login_field" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
        <br />
        <div id="submit-div">
          <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It looks like it more or less is. Although the menu looks bloated vertically (it has dead space below the buttons). It also does not appear to be rendering correctly without images. I feel this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Point is that the menu bar height is defined by the <a> contained in <li> (<a> font-size and the padding top & bottom which is 14px). On the other hand, you also have your search boxe with several elements where height is defined or other padding as well. I would try to refine the CSS with a fixed height on your menu bar, and play with line height on various nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well... It seems that your CSS is a bit messy to achieve the rendering you want. If I were you, I'll try to simplify it first...
Moreover, on the provided sample, we can not know the targeted rendering: You want to decrease height of the menu bar, or increase height of the search box?

Below a CSS sample (taken from yours) where search box height is increased to fit the menu bar's height. A not good looking CSS, as a lot of sizes are hardcoded here....

```
.fa {
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
/*hack stack-overflow*/

ul::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li.left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
li.right {
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
li span:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
li#login {
  position: relative;
}
li#login form {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
li#login:hover form {
  display: block;
}
input.login_field {
  margin: 10px;
}
#submit-div {
  text-align: center;
}
#form-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
}
.nav-list {
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
#dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 43px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
#dropdown:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.current-selection {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.in-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
#search-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
#search-box:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.go-button {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.go-button:hover {
  background-color: #ff7300;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what can I change to meke it not hard coded?

Comment: Roughly, set a given height and line-height to your root container (the same value). Then, all nested elements can have their height set to 100%. So, if you need to change the main height, you'll just have to change the one defined in the root container. Of course, this also involves to remove all included padding-top and padding-bottom (simplify things as well). Be aware that font awesome change line-height (so override your '.fa' to the inherit value). The only pain point is the included input, where another height should be passed as well (height 100% for input is no working).